# JPA::Multiple inheritance

Tags: inheritance, jpa

I have the following structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "docType")
@DiscriminatorValue("DOC")
public class Document implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
….
}


@Entity @Inheritance @DiscriminatorValue("CONTRACT")
@Table(name = "Contract")
public class Contract extends Document {

}
```

Now I need to implement another module with similar structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Transaction")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "transType")
@DiscriminatorValue("TR")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
….
}

@Entity @Inheritance @DiscriminatorValue("SPD")
@Table(name = "Spd")
public class SPD extends Transaction {

}

@Entity @Inheritance @DiscriminatorValue("TD")
@Table(name = "TD")
public class TD extends Transaction {

}
```

But, suddenly it turned out that TD should be also Document! Theoretically, TD should also extend Document But what to do with ids? Have no clue how to manage them…

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if this question still needs answering but it should be nice if you could explain what you mean by `TD`. Sun's Java coding guidelines advice against using abrevations. I suppose for this reason.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not allowed in java for many reasons, maybe you should take a look at design patterns (maybe decorator, depending on what you want to to achieve). If your design requires multiple inheritance it's probably a bad design